# crystal reports : is this a custom function?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm customizing a crystal report which was developed before me.  One of the custom formulas includes the line:

```
FreeFormText("kIMShipWhse")
```

Is this a built-in or custom function?

Answer (score 1):

UFL-based functions are listed below the 'Additional Functions' node.  Custom functions are listed below the 'Custom Functions' node.  The remaining functions are 'native' functions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a custom UFL function, Only way to check is to run the report. If it's part of a custom UFL Crystal will flag it up before it tries to run.